# Mongoose validation issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I currently have the following schema:

```
Schema({
    _id: { type: Number, default: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 24 * 60 * 60 },
    userID: { type: Number, require },
    assignmentID: {
        type: Number,
        validate: {

            validator: function (v) {
                if (!v) {
                    Promise.reject(false);
                }
                else {
                    Assignment.findById(v, (assignmentErr, assignmentDoc) => {
                        if(assignmentErr || !assignmentDoc){
                            Promise.reject(false);
                        }
                        else{
                            Promise.resolve(true);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            message: 'Invalid assignment ID.'
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is that I keep getting warnings in the console that I am not handling the rejected promises. Also the document is saved in the database even though the promise is rejected.

The way I save the new document is the following:

```
schema.save((err, savedDoc) => {
}
```

How can I solve this issue or is there a better way to do complex validation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
 assignmentID: {
    type: Number,
    validate: {

        validator: function (v) {
            if (!v) {
               return Promise.reject(false);
            }

            return Assignment.findById(v)
                .then(assignmentDoc => {
                    if( !assignmentDoc){
                      return  Promise.reject(false);
                    }
                    else{
                       return Promise.resolve(true);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                   return Promise.reject(error );
                })
        },
        message: 'Invalid assignment ID.'
    }
}
```

**Update**
You can also try as like as given below:

```
 assignmentID: {
    type: Number,
    validate: {

        validator: function (v) {
            if (!v) {
               return Promise.reject(false);
            }

            return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                Assignment.findById(v, (assignmentErr, assignmentDoc) => {
                    if(assignmentErr || !assignmentDoc){
                        reject(false);
                    }
                    else{
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                })
            });

        },
        message: 'Invalid assignment ID.'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it works! Could you please explain the difference between yours and mine as I am not sure I understand it fully?

Comment: As far what I can understand is that, you are `resolve/reject`, but never return it. I'm updating my answer which might be more understandable to you, thanks